# Optimization of treatment in a loop for

Tags: r, data.table

I want to finalize and why not optimize a taxi management program in real time.
The program manages the taxi ride of the nearest town.
Also the availability of taxis.
Knowing that a taxi is unavailable for an hour after which it becomes available again, and can be sent for a new ride.
A taxi in progress cannot be used, so we must assign the 2nd taxi closest to the city, if not available then the 3rd and so on..

The "taxi_manage" table will be used to manage taxi availability.
There is only one taxi per city.
Cities are represented by a numeric code (zip code)

State before traitement

```
taxi_manage

taxi_number   city    time_end   available
00001         1                        0
00002         11                       0
00003         12                       0
00004         13                       0
00005         14                       0
00006         2                        0
```

Table of the distance between each city
We will go through this table to retrieve the nearest city taxi number

```
city_distance
city  city_2  distance
1       1        0
1       11       3
1       12       8
2       2        0
2       13       4
2       14       7
```

Main table containing the taxi requests, which will be completed by the taxi number that will carry out the race.

```
taxi_request
id      time    city    selected_taxi
1      8:30       
2      8:40       
3      9:45       
4      8:32       
5      8:39       
6      8:40
```

Expected result:

After traitement

```
taxi_manage
taxi_number   city    time_end   available
00001         1          9:30          0
00002         11         9:40          0
00003         12         10:45         0
00004         13         9:39          0
00005         14         9:40          0
00006         2          9:32          0


taxi_request
id      time    city    selected_taxi
1      8:30      1       00001
2      8:40      1       00002
3      9:45      1       00001
4      8:32      2       00006
5      8:39      2       00004
6      8:40      2       00005

In id 3 the taxi number 00001 finished its run at 9:30 (see taxi_manage table), 
so it is selected because at 9:45 it is available again.
```

data:

```
taxi_manage <- data.table(
  taxi_number = c(00001,00002,00003,00004,00005,00006),
  city = c(1,11,12,13,14,2),
  time_end = c(NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  available = c(0, 0,0,0,0,0)
)

city_distance <- data.table(
  city = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  city_2 = c(1,11,12,2,13,14),
  distance = c(0, 3,8,0,4,7)
)

taxi_request<- data.table(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  time = c("8:30","8:40","9:45","8:32","8:39","8:40"),
  city = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
)

repeat_data <- function(d, n) {
  return(d[rep(seq_len(nrow(d)), n)])
}

taxi_request <- repeat_data(taxi_request, 10400)
```

Here is the program that I cannot optimize and whose processing is very long on more than several million lines. The program works with real data but not with this simplified example.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(taxi_request)){

  # update available
  request<- taxi_request %>%
    filter(id == i)

  taxi_manage <- taxi_manage %>%
    mutate(available = ifelse(hour(request$time)>=time_end,
                            0,1))

  # Check if taxi is available
  tmp <- city_distance %>%
    filter(city == request$city) %>%
    left_join(taxi_manage %>%
                select(taxi_number, time_end, available),
              by="city")

  # Choice taxi
  selected_taxi <- tmp %>%
    filter(available==0) %>%
    head(n=1) %>%
    pull(taxi_number)

  if (not_empty(selected_taxi)){
    # update taxi to be available
    taxi_manage <- taxi_manage %>%
      mutate(available=ifelse(taxi_number==selected_taxi, 1, available),
             heure_fin=ifelse(taxi_number==selected_taxi, hour(heure_dem) + 2, available),
             minute_fin=ifelse(taxi_number==selected_taxi, minute(heure_dem), available))

    # Add taxi number to taxi_request table
    taxi_request <- taxi_request %>%
      mutate(selected_taxi = ifelse(id==i, selected_taxi, selected_taxi))
  }
  else{
    taxi_request <- taxi_request %>%
      mutate(choix = ifelse(id==i, "no taxi found", selected_taxi))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is posted as a new answer, because it is a completely *different approach* to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506313/3817004) and includes a *benchmark comparison* with *makeshift and scalable datasets*.

First, a table `taxi_distances` of available taxi for each city is created by joining `city_distance` and `taxi_manage`. It is ordered by `city` and `distance` using `setkey()`. This is computed once and avoids repeated joins within the main loop.

Then, `taxi_request` is ordered by `city` and `time` using `setkey()`. It loops over cities and requests and considers the most recent requests within one 1 hour before of the actual request using a *non-equi self join* of `taxi_request`. Each subset of requests shows the taxi which are already assigned. From the sublist of available taxi for the actual city the nearest available taxi is picked using an *anti-join* (kind of `setdiff()`) and is assigned to the actual request using *update by reference* (with special treatment in case there is no nearest available taxi). The *update by reference* is important here because it conveys the information of which taxi are assigned *into the next iteration*.

The *non-equi self join* returns an empty table but `taxi_request` has been updated as a *side-effect*.

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

taxi_distances <- city_distance[taxi_manage, on = .(city_2=city), nomatch = NULL]
setkey(taxi_distances, city, distance)

setkey(taxi_request, city, time)
on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
taxi_request[, time_before := time - on_duty_duration]

taxi_request[
  taxi_request, on = .(city, time <= time, time >= time_before), by = .EACHI, 
  {
    print(.SD) # for demonstration 
    nearest_available_taxi <-
      taxi_distances[x.city][!.SD, on = .(taxi_number = assigned_taxi), 
                             first(taxi_number)]
    print(nearest_available_taxi)  # for demonstration 
    if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) 
      taxi_request[i.id, assigned_taxi := nearest_available_taxi]
    NULL
  }
]
```

> ```
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     1          <NA>   -00:35:00
> [1] "T001000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     1       T001000   -00:35:00
> 2:     2          <NA>   -00:10:00
> character(0)
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     1       T001000   -00:35:00
> 2:     2          <NA>   -00:10:00
> 3:     3          <NA>    00:15:00
> character(0)
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     2          <NA>   -00:10:00
> 2:     3          <NA>    00:15:00
> 3:     4          <NA>    00:40:00
> [1] "T001000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     3          <NA>    00:15:00
> 2:     4       T001000    00:40:00
> 3:     5          <NA>    01:05:00
> character(0)
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     6          <NA>   -00:35:00
> [1] "T002000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     6       T002000   -00:35:00
> 2:     7          <NA>   -00:10:00
> [1] "T002001"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     6       T002000   -00:35:00
> 2:     7       T002001   -00:10:00
> 3:     8          <NA>    00:15:00
> character(0)
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     7       T002001   -00:10:00
> 2:     8          <NA>    00:15:00
> 3:     9          <NA>    00:40:00
> [1] "T002000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:     8          <NA>    00:15:00
> 2:     9       T002000    00:40:00
> 3:    10          <NA>    01:05:00
> [1] "T002001"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:    11          <NA>   -00:35:00
> [1] "T003000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:    11       T003000   -00:35:00
> 2:    12          <NA>   -00:10:00
> [1] "T003001"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:    11       T003000   -00:35:00
> 2:    12       T003001   -00:10:00
> 3:    13          <NA>    00:15:00
> [1] "T003002"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:    12       T003001   -00:10:00
> 2:    13       T003002    00:15:00
> 3:    14          <NA>    00:40:00
> [1] "T003000"
>       id assigned_taxi time_before
>    <int>        <char>     <ITime>
> 1:    13       T003002    00:15:00
> 2:    14       T003000    00:40:00
> 3:    15          <NA>    01:05:00
> [1] "T003001"
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 5 cols): city,time,time,assigned_taxi,time_before
> ```

```
taxi_request
```

> ```
>        id    city     time assigned_taxi time_before
>     <int>  <char>  <ITime>        <char>     <ITime>
>  1:     1 C001000 00:25:00       T001000   -00:35:00
>  2:     2 C001000 00:50:00          <NA>   -00:10:00
>  3:     3 C001000 01:15:00          <NA>    00:15:00
>  4:     4 C001000 01:40:00       T001000    00:40:00
>  5:     5 C001000 02:05:00          <NA>    01:05:00
>  6:     6 C002000 00:25:00       T002000   -00:35:00
>  7:     7 C002000 00:50:00       T002001   -00:10:00
>  8:     8 C002000 01:15:00          <NA>    00:15:00
>  9:     9 C002000 01:40:00       T002000    00:40:00
> 10:    10 C002000 02:05:00       T002001    01:05:00
> 11:    11 C003000 00:25:00       T003000   -00:35:00
> 12:    12 C003000 00:50:00       T003001   -00:10:00
> 13:    13 C003000 01:15:00       T003002    00:15:00
> 14:    14 C003000 01:40:00       T003000    00:40:00
> 15:    15 C003000 02:05:00       T003001    01:05:00
> ```

#### Data

As I do not have a access to OP's production data, I have created a dummy dataset consisting of 3 cities, 6 taxi, 15 requests, and a constant request interval of 25 minutes (2.4 requests per hour). In order to cover several uses cases, the 1st city has one taxi, the 2nd city 2 taxi, etc. So, there will be a fews requests for which no taxi is available.

```
req_interval <- 25L * 60L # seconds 
n_city <- 3L
n_taxi <- seq(n_city)
n_req_per_city <- 5L
stopifnot(n_req_per_city * req_interval <= as.ITime("23:59:59"))
n_req <- n_req_per_city * n_city

tmp <- unlist(Vectorize(rep.int)(n_taxi, n_taxi))

fmt <- "C%03i%03i"
city_distance <- data.table(
  city = sprintf(fmt, tmp, 0L),
  city_2 = sprintf(fmt, tmp, rowid(tmp) - 1L),
  distance = rowid(tmp) - 1L
)

fmt <- "T%03i%03i"
taxi_manage <- data.table(
  taxi_number = sprintf(fmt, tmp, rowid(tmp) - 1L),
  city = city_distance$city_2,
  time_end = as.ITime(rep("00:00", length(tmp))),
  ride_count = rep(0L, length(tmp))
)

taxi_request <- data.table(
  id = seq(n_req),
  city = rep(unique(city_distance$city), each = n_req_per_city), 
  time = as.ITime(req_interval * rep((seq(n_req_per_city)), n_city)), 
  assigned_taxi = rep(NA_character_, n_req)
)


city_distance
```

> ```
>       city  city_2 distance
>     <char>  <char>    <int>
> 1: C001000 C001000        0
> 2: C002000 C002000        0
> 3: C002000 C002001        1
> 4: C003000 C003000        0
> 5: C003000 C003001        1
> 6: C003000 C003002        2
> ```

```
taxi_manage
```

> ```
>    taxi_number    city time_end ride_count
>         <char>  <char>  <ITime>      <int>
> 1:     T001000 C001000 00:00:00          0
> 2:     T002000 C002000 00:00:00          0
> 3:     T002001 C002001 00:00:00          0
> 4:     T003000 C003000 00:00:00          0
> 5:     T003001 C003001 00:00:00          0
> 6:     T003002 C003002 00:00:00          0
> ```

```
taxi_request
```

> ```
>        id    city     time assigned_taxi
>     <int>  <char>  <ITime>        <char>
>  1:     1 C001000 00:25:00          <NA>
>  2:     2 C001000 00:50:00          <NA>
>  3:     3 C001000 01:15:00          <NA>
>  4:     4 C001000 01:40:00          <NA>
>  5:     5 C001000 02:05:00          <NA>
>  6:     6 C002000 00:25:00          <NA>
>  7:     7 C002000 00:50:00          <NA>
>  8:     8 C002000 01:15:00          <NA>
>  9:     9 C002000 01:40:00          <NA>
> 10:    10 C002000 02:05:00          <NA>
> 11:    11 C003000 00:25:00          <NA>
> 12:    12 C003000 00:50:00          <NA>
> 13:    13 C003000 01:15:00          <NA>
> 14:    14 C003000 01:40:00          <NA>
> 15:    15 C003000 02:05:00          <NA>
> ```

#### Benchmark

The benchmark compares 5 variants

1. The `for` loop approach from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506313/3817004)
2. The code variant using grouping `by = id` from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506313/3817004)
3. The performance improvement which pulls one join out of the loop from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72506313/3817004)
4. The *self-join* approach from this answer (with an edit to  avoid a large cartesian join)
5. The *self-join* approach from this answer but using `setdiff()` instead of  the *anti-join*

The runs were performed for three different use cases, all with 10000 requests:

- n_city: 1, n_taxi: 1, n_request: 10000, req_interval: 8
- n_city: 10, n_taxi: 55, n_request: 10000, req_interval: 86
- n_city: 100, n_taxi: 5050, n_request: 10000, req_interval: 863

As can bee seen from the chart below, variant 5 is 3 to 5 times faster than variant 1:

[image]

In addition, variant 5 allocates less memory than any other variant. Variant 1 allocates more than 5 times more memory than variant 5 as can be seen from the printed benchmark results:

> ```
>    expression n_req n_city    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
>    <bch:expr> <int>  <int> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
>  1 v1         10000      1 30.41s 31.19s    0.0318    1.97GB    1.42      3   134      1.57m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  2 v2         10000      1 33.42s 33.62s    0.0296    2.43GB    1.12      3   114      1.69m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  3 v3         10000      1 19.67s 19.98s    0.0503    1.41GB    1.14      3    68     59.63s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  4 v4         10000      1 18.43s 18.89s    0.0532    1.58GB    1.15      3    65     56.39s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  5 v5         10000      1 11.15s 11.18s    0.0889    1.17GB    1.39      3    47     33.76s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  6 v1         10000     10 34.72s 34.81s    0.0278     2.3GB    0.815     3    88       1.8m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  7 v2         10000     10 36.43s 36.65s    0.0272    2.64GB    0.645     3    71      1.83m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  8 v3         10000     10 18.74s 19.44s    0.0507    1.45GB    0.659     3    39     59.19s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  9 v4         10000     10 18.38s 18.54s    0.0536    1.52GB    0.679     3    38     55.99s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 10 v5         10000     10 11.53s 11.69s    0.0858    1.13GB    0.801     3    28     34.96s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 11 v1         10000    100  1.15m  1.18m    0.0142    7.88GB    0.356     3    75      3.52m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 12 v2         10000    100 59.21s     1m    0.0167    7.25GB    0.300     3    54         3m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 13 v3         10000    100 23.71s 24.19s    0.0402    2.71GB    0.429     3    32      1.24m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 14 v4         10000    100 21.77s 22.12s    0.0451    1.68GB    0.496     3    33      1.11m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 15 v5         10000    100 15.13s 15.21s    0.0652    1.29GB    0.565     3    26     46.02s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> ```

#### Benchmark code

```
library(data.table)
library(bench)

bm2 <- press(
  n_req =  c(10000L),
  n_city = c(1L, 10L, 100L),
  {
    n_taxi <- seq(n_city)
    n_req_per_city <- n_req / n_city
    req_interval <- 
      as.integer(as.ITime("23:59:59") / n_req_per_city)
    stopifnot(n_req_per_city * req_interval <= as.ITime("23:59:59"))
    
    tmp <- unlist(Vectorize(rep.int)(n_taxi, n_taxi))

    fmt <- "C%04i%04i"
    city_distance <- data.table(
      city = sprintf(fmt, tmp, 0L),
      city_2 = sprintf(fmt, tmp, rowid(tmp) - 1L),
      distance = rowid(tmp) - 1L
    )
    # city_distance
    
    fmt <- "T%04i%04i"
    taxi_manage0 <- data.table(
      taxi_number = sprintf(fmt, tmp, rowid(tmp) - 1L),
      city = city_distance$city_2,
      time_end = as.ITime(rep("00:00", length(tmp))),
      ride_count = rep(0L, length(tmp))
    )
    # taxi_manage
    
    taxi_request0 <- data.table(
      id = seq(n_req),
      city = rep(unique(city_distance$city), each = n_req_per_city), 
      time = as.ITime(req_interval * rep((seq(n_req_per_city)), n_city)), 
      assigned_taxi = rep(NA_character_, n_req)
    )
    # taxi_request0
    
    cat(sprintf("\nn_city: %i, n_taxi: %i, n_request: %i, req_interval: %i\n",
                uniqueN(city_distance$city), 
                uniqueN(taxi_manage0$taxi_number), 
                nrow(taxi_request0), 
                req_interval))
    
    mark(
      v1 = {
        taxi_manage <- copy(taxi_manage0)
        taxi_request <- copy(taxi_request0)
        on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
        setkey(taxi_manage, taxi_number)
        setkey(taxi_request, id)
        
        for (req_id in taxi_request$id) {
          available_taxi <- taxi_manage[taxi_request[req_id], on = .(time_end < time)]
          nearest_available_taxi <- 
            city_distance[available_taxi, on = .(city = i.city, city_2 = city), 
                          nomatch = NULL][
                            , taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
          if(length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) {
            taxi_request[req_id, assigned_taxi := nearest_available_taxi]
            taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, 
                        time_end := taxi_request[req_id, time + on_duty_duration]]
          }
        }
        taxi_request
      },
      v2 = {
        taxi_manage <- copy(taxi_manage0)
        taxi_request <- copy(taxi_request0)
        on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
        setkey(taxi_manage, taxi_number)
        
        taxi_request[, assigned_taxi := {
          available_taxi <- taxi_manage[.SD, on = .(time_end < time)]
          nearest_available_taxi <- 
            city_distance[available_taxi, on = .(city = i.city, city_2 = city), 
                          nomatch = NULL][
                            , taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
          request_time <- .SD$time
          taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, 
                      time_end := request_time + on_duty_duration]
          if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) nearest_available_taxi else NA
        },
        by = id]
        taxi_request
      },
      v3 = {
        taxi_manage <- copy(taxi_manage0)
        taxi_request <- copy(taxi_request0)
        taxi_distances <- city_distance[taxi_manage, on = .(city_2=city), nomatch = NULL]
        setkey(taxi_distances, taxi_number)
        
        on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
        
        taxi_request[, assigned_taxi := {
          nearest_available_taxi <-
            .SD[taxi_distances, on = .(city, time > time_end), 
                nomatch = NULL, taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
          request_time <- .SD$time
          taxi_distances[nearest_available_taxi, 
                         time_end := request_time + on_duty_duration]
          if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) nearest_available_taxi else NA
        },
        by = id]
        taxi_request[]
      },
      v4 = {
        taxi_manage <- copy(taxi_manage0)
        taxi_request <- copy(taxi_request0)
        
        taxi_distances <- city_distance[taxi_manage, on = .(city_2=city), nomatch = NULL]
        setkey(taxi_distances, city, distance)
        
        setkey(taxi_request, city, time)
        on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
        taxi_request[, time_before := time - on_duty_duration]
        
        taxi_request[
          taxi_request, on = .(city, time <= time, time >= time_before), by = .EACHI, 
          {
            nearest_available_taxi <-
              taxi_distances[first(x.city)][!.SD, on = .(taxi_number = assigned_taxi), 
                                            first(taxi_number)]
            if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) 
              taxi_request[i.id, assigned_taxi := nearest_available_taxi]
            NULL
          }
          ]
        taxi_request[, time_before := NULL][]
      },
      v5 = {
        taxi_manage <- copy(taxi_manage0)
        taxi_request <- copy(taxi_request0)
        
        taxi_distances <- city_distance[taxi_manage, on = .(city_2=city), nomatch = NULL]
        setkey(taxi_distances, city, distance)
        
        setkey(taxi_request, city, time)
        on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
        taxi_request[, time_before := time - on_duty_duration]
        
        taxi_request[
          taxi_request, on = .(city, time <= time, time >= time_before), by = .EACHI, 
          {
            nearest_available_taxi <- first(setdiff(
              taxi_distances[first(x.city), taxi_number], 
              .SD[, assigned_taxi]))
            if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) 
              taxi_request[i.id, assigned_taxi := nearest_available_taxi]
            NULL
          }
          ]
        taxi_request[, time_before := NULL][]
      },
      check = function(x, y) all.equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE),
      min_time = 10, 
      min_iterations = 3L
    ) # mark
  }  
) # press

bm2
ggplot2::autoplot(bm2)
```

#### Parallelisation (an experiment)

As the [OP has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483426/optimization-of-treatment-in-a-loop-for/72599108#comment128261692_72599108) that the cities are grouped by region with disjoint cities and [reportedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483426/optimization-of-treatment-in-a-loop-for/72599108#comment128090024_72506313) has tried to speed up computation using `foreach()` and `%dopar%` I have started to experiment with paralleisation as well.

The first experiment uses the multithreading capabilities of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), `setDTthreads(2L)`. Unfortunately, the benchmark shows no speed-up for `v6` (2 threads) vs `v5` (1 thread) which might be due to hardware limitations.  `v4` was included to confirm that `v5` is the faster version.

[image]

> ```
>    expression n_req n_city    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
>    <bch:expr> <int>  <int> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
>  1 v4         20000    200  48.5s  48.5s    0.0206    3.44GB    0.639     1    31      48.5s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  2 v5         20000    200  31.3s  31.3s    0.0320    2.65GB    0.768     1    24      31.3s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  3 v6         20000    200  32.4s  32.4s    0.0309    2.65GB    0.710     1    23      32.4s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  4 v4         10000    200  23.1s  23.1s    0.0433    1.73GB    0.866     1    20      23.1s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  5 v5         10000    200  14.3s  14.3s    0.0698    1.32GB    1.05      1    15      14.3s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  6 v6         10000    200  14.3s  14.3s    0.0700    1.32GB    0.980     1    14      14.3s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  7 v4         20000    100  42.9s  42.9s    0.0233    3.36GB    0.630     1    27      42.9s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  8 v5         20000    100    30s    30s    0.0334    2.56GB    0.534     1    16        30s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
>  9 v6         20000    100  28.9s  28.9s    0.0346    2.56GB    0.485     1    14      28.9s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 10 v4         10000    100    21s    21s    0.0476    1.69GB    0.571     1    12        21s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 11 v5         10000    100  14.1s  14.1s    0.0711    1.29GB    0.711     1    10      14.1s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 12 v6         10000    100  14.2s  14.2s    0.0706    1.29GB    0.706     1    10      14.2s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> ```

Anyhow, `v5` took about 30 seconds to process 20000 requests and less than 15 seconds to process 10000 requests. The number of cities (and the number of taxi) in the makeshift datasets seem to have little effect on run time.

For OP's production dataset with 900000 requests, processing may take about 30 minutes (assuming linear behaviour). So, the question if it is worthwhile to investigate parallelisation further.

#### Additional benchmarks

To verify my assumption that the `v5` code is fast enough to handle OP's production dataset I have conducted additional benchmarks with 10k, 20k, 40k, and 80k requests.

> ```
>   expression n_req n_city     min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory time 
>   <bch:expr> <dbl>  <int> <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
> 1 v5         80000    100   1.98m  1.98m   0.00841   10.13GB    0.471     1    56      1.98m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 2 v5         40000    100   1.08m  1.08m   0.0154     5.12GB    0.200     1    13      1.08m <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 3 v5         20000    100  30.06s 30.06s   0.0333     2.56GB    0.266     1     8     30.06s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> 4 v5         10000    100  15.43s 15.43s   0.0648     1.29GB    0.324     1     5     15.43s <data… <Rpro… <ben…
> ```

Plotting the run times vs number of requests on *double logarithmic (log-log) scale*

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bm4) +
  aes(n_req, median, label = as.character(median)) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = bm4$n_req) + scale_y_log10() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel()
```

indicates that run times scales linearily with problem size and that run times of 25 to 30 minutes for 900k requests might be achievable (on the system used for benchmarking; your mileage may vary):

[image]

However, memory allocation might be a greater challenge than runtimes

```
ggplot(bm4) +
  aes(n_req, mem_alloc, label = as.character(mem_alloc)) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = bm4$n_req) + scale_y_log10() +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel()
```

[image]

Note the log-log scale. Again, memory allocation varies linearily with problem size. However, for the 80k case about 10 GBytes of memory were allocated. Extrapolating this to 900k, more than 110 Gbytes of memory would be required.

The conclusion is that splitting up the problem in smaller chunks by regions might be necessary to comply with the available memory.

Comment: This approach is perfect and significantly reduces processing time. Quick question, you suggested that splitting the data into multiple groups might also reduce processing time. Cities of taxi requests (from data distances too) are grouped by region. Example region "A" contains the cities "C001000" and "C002000", while region "B" contains "C003000" and "C004000". Could using a loop per region reduce the processing time? If so what would be the best way to implement it in current approach?

Comment: @DaoudiKarim. My recent benchmark results (see my edits) indicate that splitting up the problem into smaller chunks might be necessary to comply with the available memory on your computer rather than gaining speed-up.

Comment: I find the benchmark really very interesting and complete. So I will try to adapt the code for slicing by region, and using foreach() and %dopar% from the parallel package. The challenge will be to use the foreach on a data table in an optimized way.

Comment: I modified the data part of the initial post, by multiplying data (add "repeat_data()" function) in order to obtain the volume in production. There are 160000 requests and the processing takes 5 minutes, we will need 1000 runs to obtain an average, which would take 5 x 1000 = 5000 or 83 hours. The processing is too long, knowing that the server has 6 cores of which only 3 will be used per data table. Do you think another method should be used?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to assign to each taxi request a car which is

1. available and
2. located in the nearest city

As the question is tagged [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), here is a solution which uses [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax utilizing *non-equi join*, *assigment by reference*, and *keyed subsetting*.

Note that the input data has been modified to include an additional use case (*no taxi available*), to comply with syntax rules, and to avoid costly type conversions.

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
setkey(taxi_manage, taxi_number)
setkey(taxi_request, id)

for (req_id in taxi_request$id) {
  available_taxi <- taxi_manage[taxi_request[req_id], on = .(time_end < time)]
  nearest_available_taxi <- 
    city_distance[available_taxi, on = .(city = i.city, city_2 = city), 
                  nomatch = NULL][
                    , taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
  if(length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) {
    taxi_request[req_id, assigned_taxi := nearest_available_taxi]
    taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, 
                time_end := taxi_request[req_id, time + on_duty_duration]]
    taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, ride_count := ride_count + 1L]
  }
}
```

The final result is

```
taxi_request
```

> ```
>        id     time   city assigned_taxi
>    <char>  <ITime> <char>        <char>
> 1:      1 08:30:00      1         00001
> 2:      2 08:40:00      1         00002
> 3:      3 09:45:00      1         00001
> 4:      4 08:32:00      2         00006
> 5:      5 08:39:00      2         00004
> 6:      6 08:40:00      2         00005
> 7:      7 08:42:00      2          <NA>
> ```

Note that request #7 has no taxi assigned as no taxi was available at the time of the request.

The last status of the managed taxis was

```
taxi_manage
```

> ```
>    taxi_number   city time_end ride_count
>         <char> <char>  <ITime>      <int>
> 1:       00001      1 10:45:00          2
> 2:       00002     11 09:40:00          1
> 3:       00003     12 00:00:00          0
> 4:       00004     13 09:39:00          1
> 5:       00005     14 09:40:00          1
> 6:       00006      2 09:32:00          1
> ```

#### Explanation

- Please, see also the comments in the **Data** section for additional explanations.
- *Keys* are set for both `taxi_manage` and `taxi_request`. This simplifies codying because we can subset with, e.g., `taxi_manage["00001"]` instead of `taxi_manage[taxi_number == "00001"]`. In addition, *binary search* is used for subsetting.
- The code processes one taxi request after the other in order of occurrence in `taxi_request`. It is assumed that the requests are already ordered by the time of request (at least for each city).
- Within the loop, all *available taxi* (regardless of location) are found using a *non-equi join* with the condition `time_end < time`.
- With a second join, the distances to the locations of the available taxi are being appended and the nearest available taxi is picked. In case no taxi is available, a vector of length `0` is returned.
- Finally, `taxi_request` and `taxi_manage` are *updated by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole object.

#### Code variant

For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention that [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax allows for an equivalent code using grouping `by = id` instead of the `for` loop. Note that references to `taxi_request[req_id]` are replaced by `.SD`.

```
on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
setkey(taxi_manage, taxi_number)

taxi_request[, assigned_taxi := {
  available_taxi <- taxi_manage[.SD, on = .(time_end < time)]
  nearest_available_taxi <- 
    city_distance[available_taxi, on = .(city = i.city, city_2 = city), 
                  nomatch = NULL][
                    , taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
  request_time <- .SD$time
  taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, 
              time_end := request_time + on_duty_duration]
  taxi_manage[nearest_available_taxi, ride_count := ride_count + 1L]
  if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) nearest_available_taxi else NA
},
by = id]
```

Unfortunately, I cannot assess the impact on performance as the sample dataset is far too small.

#### Performance considerations

The code above involves two joins per taxi request. One join can be pulled out of the loop by creating a `taxi_distances` table which contains the related cities, distances and taxi

```
taxi_distances <- city_distance[taxi_manage, on = .(city_2=city), nomatch = NULL]
setkey(taxi_distances, taxi_number)
```

> ```
>      city city_2 distance taxi_number time_end ride_count
>    <char> <char>    <num>      <char>  <ITime>      <int>
> 1:      1      1        0       00001 00:00:00          0
> 2:      1     11        3       00002 00:00:00          0
> 3:      1     12        8       00003 00:00:00          0
> 4:      2     13        4       00004 00:00:00          0
> 5:      2     14        7       00005 00:00:00          0
> 6:      2      2        0       00006 00:00:00          0
> ```

Note that taxi appear only once *just by chance*; in case one taxi serves more than one city there might by multiple entries for the same taxi.

Now, bookkeeping is done in `taxi_distances` instead of `taxi_manage`. The modified code becomes:

```
on_duty_duration <- 1L * 60L *60L # 1 hour in seconds
taxi_request[, assigned_taxi := {
  nearest_available_taxi <-
    .SD[taxi_distances, on = .(city, time > time_end), 
        nomatch = NULL, taxi_number[which.min(distance)]]
  request_time <- .SD$time
  taxi_distances[nearest_available_taxi, 
                 time_end := request_time + on_duty_duration]
  taxi_distances[nearest_available_taxi, ride_count := ride_count + 1L]
  if (length(nearest_available_taxi) > 0) nearest_available_taxi else NA
},
by = id]
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

taxi_manage <- data.table(
  taxi_number = c("00001","00002","00003","00004","00005","00006"),
  city = c("1","11","12","13","14","2"),
  time_end = as.ITime(rep("00:00", 6L)),
  ride_count = rep(0L, 6L)
)

city_distance <- data.table(
  city = c("1","1","1","2","2","2"),
  city_2 = c("1","11","12","2","13","14"),
  distance = c(0, 3,8,0,4,7)
)

taxi_request<- data.table(
  id = c("1","2","3","4","5","6", "7"),
  time = as.ITime(c("8:30","8:40","9:45","8:32","8:39","8:40","8:42")),
  city = c("1","1","1","2","2","2","2"),
  assigned_taxi = rep(NA_character_, 7L)
)
```

Please note

- all id columns have been coerced to type character (which is more realistic)
- columns `time_end`, `ride_count`, and `assigned_taxi` have been initialized with sensible values
- columns `time` and `time_end` are of class `ITime`  which is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day (see `?data.table::ITime`)

Comment: It's exactly what I needed. By executing on 1000 iterations the treatment lasts 35 seconds. The real data have 900000 rows, so processing should take 900 *35 = 31500 or about 9 hours. I tried running a parallel loop with the following syntax, it reduces to 25 seconds for thousand iterations: `finalMatrix <- foreach(i=1:1000, .combine=cbind, .packages="data.table") %dopar% {` Do you think it is possible to reduce the time?

Comment: @DaoudiKarim, I am looking into an improved version which works city-wise. But performance may strongly depend on the structure of your data. I understand that there are 900000 requests. From how many different cities do come the requests? How many taxi do you have in total? How many taxi belong to one city, i.e., column `city` in table `city_distance` on average?

Comment: There are 456 cities, each city contains an unique specific taxi. 900,000 taxi requests are to be expected in a year. In the "city_distance" table contains 250000 rows, and one city can be associated on average with 850 other cities.

Comment: Thank you for the details, @DaoudiKarim. Perhaps, I have not completly understood. If there are 456 cities with a taxi in each, how can each city be connected with 850 other cities on average? Are there other cities without a tyxi?

Comment: @DaoudiKarim, just a thought about parallelization: It might be worthwhile to consider splitting requests and taxi data by city. This will reduce the volume of data to handle and thus might speed up processing.

Comment: yes there are cities without taxi

Comment: Thank you for you precious help. I'm not stuck on data.table, I just understood it to be better for large data, do you think it's better to use something other than data.table? your opinion interests me

Comment: If you are looking for faster methods for large datasets, you may have a look at [`Rcpp`](https://www.rcpp.org/) which integrates C++ code with R or at Seb Krantz' [`collapse`](https://github.com/SebKrantz/collapse) package. The latter is part of [`fastverse`](https://github.com/fastverse/fastverse), a suite of high-performance packages.